# CORS error when try to generateEmbedUrlForRegisteredUser

Tags: angular, cors, aws-sdk, amazon-quicksight

I have an angular application using keycloak to authenticate. I'm trying to generate a URL to embed a quicksight dashboard, but I'm getting this CORS error when I try to execute the method `generateEmbedUrlForRegisteredUser`.

I was able to retrieve my tokens, `AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityRequest` and generate an `AWS.credential`. But the next step, which is to generate the URL, gives me this CORS error in this endpoint `https://quicksight.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/accounts/xxxxx/embed-url/registered-user`.

Here is a sample:

```
 const quicksightClient = this.aws.quickSight();
 const generateEmbedUrlForAnonymousUserParams = {
    AwsAccountId: 'xxxxx',
    onLifetimeInMinutes: 5,
    UserArn:
        'arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/xxxx',
    ExperienceConfiguration: {
        Dashboard: {
            InitialDashboardId: 'xxxxx',
        },
    },
};

quicksightClient.generateEmbedUrlForRegisteredUser(
    generateEmbedUrlForAnonymousUserParams,
    function (err, data) {
        ...
    }
);
```

I am trying to follow these steps:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/embedded-analytics-dashboards-for-everyone.html

Comment: running into the same issue. did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Andreas I guess the front can't make this request. My team opt to create a server side endpoint to generate the url and I'm consuming it in my front-end

Comment: @ThaisMolica that's right, as per my answer below you can't use these endpoints from a browser. Would appreciate if you could mark my answer as the resolution for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and then realised that the docs tell you why:

> Currently, you can use `GetDashboardEmbedURL` only from the server, not from the user's browser.

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-quicksight/classes/getdashboardembedurlcommand.html

I got a CORS error when using `RegisterUserCommand` as well, so it looks many of QuickSight JS SDK endpoints are enabled for server side access (NodeJS) and will not work in the browser.

I think it's fair to assume that `generateEmbedUrlForRegisteredUser` falls into the same criteria, even if not specified in the docs.

My approach was to create a server side endpoint to generate the dashboard URL. You can also use lambda for this if you don't have a backend app.